# Editable midi editor in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm looking to make a midi editor for UWP (in c#). I've got many plans but I'm lost on exactly how to display it. What is a good UI control to start with for displaying my notes (sort of like Garage Band). I'm making my own UserControl but I don't know if I should go fancy with grids, or use a canvas in front of some form for displaying it.

Comment: None, you should create your own, I would recommend to use a picturebox as base, inherit from it and then draw the.. cells? partiture? not sure how you want to represent the data as there are many forms.

Comment: Kind of like nch Mixpad, cells

Comment: PictureBox is not available in UWP, it's in WinForms. 

I'd recommend templating your own control, here's a useful [link](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/building-a-custom-uwp-control-with-xaml-and-the-composition-api/) that goes through the creation of a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

Using grid might be simpler at first, but if you want to make complex custom UI it's better to write it from scratch.

For this I recommend [Win2d](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/) which makes it very easy to draw custom interface in your app.